# функция ReadFile() window API

Tags: c++, winapi

Я хотел вывести информация из файла в консоль.

```
int main() {
    DWORD lpBuffer, dwTemp;
    wchar_t szPathToFile[] = L"C:\\Users\\Professional\\Desktop\\File.txt";
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(szPathToFile, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile) {
        printf("problem");
    }
    bool processEnd = ReadFile(hFile, &lpBuffer, sizeof(lpBuffer), &dwTemp, NULL);
    if (!processEnd) {
        printf("problem asyncio or failure!");
    }
    cout << lpBuffer;
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 0;
}
```

сохраняю файл с данными в виде цифры 1.
Запускаю:

`3435973681`

Пробую еще, но с другими цифрами: 2, 3;
Закономерно увеличивает число на 1.

Вопрос: откуда берется такое число?

тип выводимых данный - unsigned long.

Comment: Пишете, наверное, в текстовом виде? А читаете в бинарном...

Comment: А зачем вобще при наличии стандартной библиотеки работать через API? что это вам дает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, саму цифру считывала как символ.
Решение - приведение типов.

```
cout << (char)lpBuffer;
```

Comment: Это плохое решение. Во-первых с-style cast плохо само по себе, а во вторых проще было бы сразу указать правильный тип буфера.